# Symfony 2.8.1 error after installation

Tags: php, symfony

I am using **Symfony 2.8.1** and work on **Windows 8** with **WAMP Server 2**, **Apache 2.4.2** and PHP **5.4.3**
I have installed Symfony with the command tool with success, but when I try to access the url **http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/** I get this error message :

**`FatalErrorException in ProxyGenerator.php line 62: Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`**

Then this list of errors :

```
in ProxyGenerator.php line 62
at DebugClassLoader->loadClass() in EntityManager.php line 0
at ProxyFactory->__construct() in EntityManager.php line 166
at EntityManager->__construct() in EntityManager.php line 850
at EntityManager::create() in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 605
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService() in Container.php line 312
at Container->get() in classes.php line 6695
at ManagerRegistry->getService() in classes.php line 6665
at AbstractManagerRegistry->getManagers() in DoctrineDataCollector.php line 65
at DoctrineDataCollector->collect() in Profiler.php line 218
at Profiler->collect() in ProfilerListener.php line 128
at ProfilerListener->onKernelResponse() in WrappedListener.php line 61
at call_user_func() in WrappedListener.php line 61
at WrappedListener->__invoke() in classes.php line 1853
at call_user_func() in classes.php line 1853
at EventDispatcher->doDispatch() in classes.php line 1771
at EventDispatcher->dispatch() in TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 132
at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch() in HttpKernel.php line 179
at HttpKernel->filterResponse() in HttpKernel.php line 161
at HttpKernel->handleRaw() in HttpKernel.php line 62
at HttpKernel->handle() in ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php line 69
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() in Kernel.php line 185
at Kernel->handle() in app_dev.php line 30
at {main}() in app_dev.php line 0
```

On line 62 of ProxyGenerator.php :

```
protected $placeholders = [
    'baseProxyInterface'   => Proxy::class,
    'additionalProperties' => '',
];
```

The issue seems to be this :

```
Proxy::class
```

When I change it into that :

```
'Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Proxy'
```

It works !

I'd like to know what's happening and if the change I made is a solution for real.

Any thoughts ?
Thanks.

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword. The lexer is treating it as such (`T_CLASS` token). a `class` keyword occurrence is expected to be followed by a class name, and is not expected to be preceded by a scope resolution operator (`::`). `Proxy::` is expected to be followed by a constant name, or a static variable name, not a class token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a **PHP** version problem. You need at least **PHP 5.5**.

It's because `ProxyGenerator` uses the static `class` keyword for class name resolution.

So, update your **Wamp** server to something where **PHP > 5.5** and you should be good to go !

Source :
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Comment: Actually, S2.8 will run fine on php 5.3.  I think the user may have tried to update Doctrine or do something else strange.  In fact, I suspect they may actually have installed S3.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks, that was exactly that !

Answer (score 5):

You can run `composer update` to re-install the vendor library versions that are compatible with your PHP version.

Comment: This is the right answer. The vendor provided by Symfony on installation are built on SensioLabs' servers, so they might run on PHP 5.5.
 
If you run a proper "composer update" manually right after installing Symfony, composer will automatically remove incompatible packages and install versions that are compatible with your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 2.8 is compatible with PHP 5.3.9 or higher. However, one of the external libraries used by Symfony, which is called Doctrine, requires PHP 5.5 or higher.

For now the only solution is to update your PHP installation. In the next Symfony 2.8.x version this may be solved by restricting the version used for the Doctrine library.

Comment: It's sufficient to run `composer update` which will install a new version of `doctrine/common` that is compatible with PHP 5.4 (the 1.6 release of that package requires PHP 5.5).

Comment: @xabbuh yes, but it's a bad solution. The package provided by Symfony should be compatible with the lowest dependencies declared (to be compatible with PHP 5.3). Then if someone wants higher dependencies, they can always update their Composer deps.